# Why is directive function not receiving data in function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to send some data to a function inside of a directive.

On the index.html page I have inserted the directive like below:

```
<div safe-total safedata="safe"></div>
```

The HTML on the directive template is shown below:

```
<div class="value"><sup>$</sup>{{totalSafe(safedata)}}</div>
```

The directive javascript is below:

```
secure.directive('safeTotal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            safedata: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/Angular/SafeTotal/safeTotal.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.totalSafe = function (object)
            {               
                var test = object;
                return "test";

            }
        }
    }
});
```

I can set a breakpoint and `var test = object` is never set with anything. However the function runs and is being called. What am I overlooking to receive the object in the function?

Comment: from what i see here, since you return "test" as string not a variable. your html will at least printout the word "test".

Comment: Yes, that is true, I was just testing to see that the function is getting hit, which it is, just trying to figure out why object isn't populated

Comment: ok, try this. i think what you bind in html is safedata = $scope.safe(empty atm) not the string "safe". So put single quote inside double quote. safedata= " 'safe' "

Comment: `<div safe-total safedata="'safe'"></div>` does pass to the function. but it only passes the string "safe"

Comment: These work on the index.html for other directives `<div manual-drop manualdata="safe.Node"></div>` that node gets passed as I'd expect

Comment: in this plunker, using your original code. the object does receive data from safe-total... http://plnkr.co/edit/Mzd5NAYFUl5yPJHuN5Nh?p=preview

Comment: it could be your html scope mess with the directive scope, like it was not isolated. I can't be sure without looking at your html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65388/discussion-between-vdj4y-and-jon-harding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. 
in this plunker, using your original code. the object does receive data from safe-total...  [plnkr.co/edit/Mzd5NAYFUl5yPJHuN5Nh?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mzd5NAYFUl5yPJHuN5Nh?p=preview)

```
  <div safe-total safedata="safeisEmpty"></div> //$(nothing)
  <div safe-total safedata="'safeisNotEmpty'"></div> //$safeisNotEmpty
```

since I don't see your html; it can be any cases, 1.like the scope of ng-controller takes over your dir-scope. 2.it can be the var safe is empty at that point of time, maybe another logic mess with it's value exactly before it is passes to safeTotal();

To check the value of scope at the point of time. You can use batarang. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

just watch the short video  about how to use it, Batarang even has tool to point and click an HTML element and shows what the value of scope is in it at that point of time. 
 it helps me to understand the value and behavior of scope(s) during different events.